# Java programming : setActionCommand() error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, awt, jbutton, actionlistener

I am developping a multiplayer Tetris-like game, with an RMI included. I have an interface (BorderLayout) with a grid of JButtons (the board) which works fines, a couple of panels on the side, and a panel at the bottom with 3 JButtons on it, which represent 3 tetris pieces.
The problem comes when I run the Client : I have a method that gets a pool of 3 pieces (and get the details on each one) when I launch the client, so I can get the name, the color, etc. to define the proper action when I clic on these JButtons.

```
public void setBoutons(Piece[] bloc) 
{   
    this.piece1 = bloc[0];
    this.piece2 = bloc[1];
    this.piece3 = bloc[2];      

    this.nompiece1 = piece1.getNom();
    this.nompiece2 = piece2.getNom();
    this.nompiece3 = piece3.getNom();

    //System.out.println(nompiece1);

    this.bouton1.setActionCommand(this.nompiece1);
    this.bouton2.setActionCommand(this.nompiece2);
    this.bouton3.setActionCommand(this.nompiece3);

    this.couleur1 = piece1.getCouleur();
    this.couleur2 = piece2.getCouleur();
    this.couleur3 = piece3.getCouleur();

    this.disposition1 = piece1.getDisposition();
    this.disposition2 = piece2.getDisposition();
    this.disposition3 = piece3.getDisposition();        

}
```

And what happens is that I can't set the ActionCommand. I tried many ways, even just using simple String like "hello" and I keep having this error :

```
Client exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Fenetre.setBoutons(Fenetre.java:174)
at Fenetre.<init>(Fenetre.java:60)
at Client.main(Client.java:22)
```

I put the whole code right below, except the actionPerformed part (takes a lot of space, if needed ask me for it) :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Fenetre extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JButton[][] cases;
    private JButton bouton1;
    private JButton bouton2;
    private JButton bouton3;
    private String nompiece1;
    private String nompiece2;
    private String nompiece3;
    private Color couleur1;
    private Color couleur2;
    private Color couleur3;
    private byte[][] disposition1;
    private byte[][] disposition2;
    private byte[][] disposition3;
    private Piece piece1;
    private Piece piece2;
    private Piece piece3;
    private byte p1;
    private byte p2;
    private byte p3;
    private Interface ninja;
    private JPanel grille;
    private JPanel zonepieces;
    private JPanel zonedroite;
    private JPanel zonehaut;
    private JLabel pseudo;
    private JLabel score;


    public Fenetre(Interface uneinterface) 
    {
        this.ninja = uneinterface;
        try 
        {
            Piece[] unpool = ninja.PoolPieces();
            this.setBoutons(unpool);
        } 
        catch (RemoteException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.p1 = 0;
        this.p2 = 0;
        this.p3 = 0;

        this.cases = new JButton[10][10];
        this.grille = new JPanel();
        this.zonepieces = new JPanel();
        this.zonedroite = new JPanel();
        this.zonehaut = new JPanel();          
        this.grille.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10, 2, 2)); 

        for(int j = 0; j<10; j++)
        {   
            for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) 
            {
                this.cases[j][i] = new JButton(" ");
                this.cases[j][i].addActionListener(this);
                this.cases[j][i].setActionCommand(""+j+i);
                this.cases[j][i].setBackground(Color.gray);
                this.grille.add(cases[j][i]);
            }
        }

        this.bouton1 = new JButton();
        this.bouton1.addActionListener(this);
        this.bouton1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        this.bouton2 = new JButton();
        this.bouton2.addActionListener(this);
        this.bouton2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        this.bouton3 = new JButton();
        this.bouton3.addActionListener(this);
        this.bouton3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        this.zonepieces.setLayout(new FlowLayout());    
        this.zonepieces.add(bouton1);    
        this.zonepieces.add(bouton2);    
        this.zonepieces.add(bouton3);
        this.pseudo = new JLabel("Pseudo");
        this.zonehaut.add(pseudo);
        this.score = new JLabel("Score");
        this.zonedroite.add(score);

        add(grille, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(zonepieces, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(zonedroite, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(zonehaut, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        this.setTitle("1010");
        this.setSize(700, 700);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void setBoutons(Piece[] bloc) 
    {
        this.piece1 = bloc[0];
        this.piece2 = bloc[1];
        this.piece3 = bloc[2];      

        this.nompiece1 = piece1.getNom();
        this.nompiece2 = piece2.getNom();
        this.nompiece3 = piece3.getNom();

        //System.out.println(nompiece1);

        this.bouton1.setActionCommand(this.nompiece1);
        this.bouton2.setActionCommand(this.nompiece2);
        this.bouton3.setActionCommand(this.nompiece3);

        this.couleur1 = piece1.getCouleur();
        this.couleur2 = piece2.getCouleur();
        this.couleur3 = piece3.getCouleur();

        this.disposition1 = piece1.getDisposition();
        this.disposition2 = piece2.getDisposition();
        this.disposition3 = piece3.getDisposition();    
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The best way to trace a NullPointerException is to debug your app with your favorite IDE and add an Exception breakpoint for `NullPointerException`.

Comment: The source problem is the setActionCommand : when I borrow it the whole thing runs just fine, but as my entire Game relies on that ActionCommand, I can't do anything with it haha

Comment: ok the minimum information we need is: which line is line 174?

Comment: this.bouton1.setActionCommand(this.nompiece1);

Comment: It's in the first bloc of code of the post. And you can find it also at the end of the entire code (3rd bloc of the post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this constructor:

```
public Fenetre(Interface uneinterface) 
{
    this.ninja = uneinterface;
    try 
    {
        Piece[] unpool = ninja.PoolPieces();
        this.setBoutons(unpool);
    } 
    catch (RemoteException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

you are calling the `setBoutons` method, which in turn accesses the `bouton1` field. But that field is only initialized later in the constructor:

```
this.bouton1 = new JButton();
```

which means it's null at the point you are calling `setBoutons`. Change your constructor to initialize the boutons first and you should be fine.

In Java, all fields that have reference types (non-primitives) are null before they are initialized.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked ! (and I feel really stupid right now)

Comment: @AlexandrevanWesel don't. everybody makes mistakes like that in the beginning. you focus on your vision and forget the nitty-gritty details. Learn to debug your app and to read stack traces. It will help you a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)